# How to write a GROUP BY SQL query

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a "Revenue" table which stores the revenue for a Company State combination.

```
Company int
State   char(2)
IsBiggestState bit
TotalRevenue numeric (10,2)
```

I need to set the IsBiggestState bit to 1 if the TotalRevenue Amount is the largest amount of all the States within a Company.

How can I write the SQL? Since I am dealing with millions of records, efficiency is of concern.

We are on SQL2008 R2.

Comment: What RDBMS and version are you using?

Comment: What if two states have the same revenue for a given company?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE A 
SET A.IsBiggestState = 1
FROM YourTable A
INNER JOIN (SELECT Company, MAX(TotalRevenue) MaxRevenue FROM YourTable
            GROUP BY Company) B
ON A.Company = B.Company AND A.TotalRevenue = B.MaxRevenue
```

Comment: You need a `GROUP BY` in your subquery.  This may also have am issue if there are two states with the same (highest) revenue, but I expect he would want them both marked which your query would do.

Comment: @JNK Oh, yes, I do. Updated my answer, thanks. And yes, I thought the same about more than one state with same highest revenue.

Answer (score 1):

This would address the problem of 2 states having the same TotalRevenue (if that is indeed a problem). It would mark only one of them as the IsBiggestState. I am not entirely sure how the performance compares to other solutions.

```
UPDATE A 
SET A.IsBiggestState = 1
FROM Revenue A
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT
        Company
        ,[State]
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Company ORDER BY TotalRevenue desc) as rownum
    FROM Revenue 
) B
ON A.Company = B.Company AND A.[State] = B.[State] AND B.rownum = 1
```

Comment: Are you sure that you can use an Alias "A" to specify the target table? I didn't think alias worked in this context.